# Formula for PRESS R-squared with weights

Tags: regression, weighted-regression

I am trying to reproduce some values of leave-one-out cross-validated (PRESS) $R^2$ in a published paper. This should be straightforward, but the authors used weighted regression, and I have yet to find a complete published exposition of PRESS $R^2$ with weights. I have my own R implementation modeled on the use of weights in lm, but I'm looking for literature to back this up. Any pointers?

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: Dead silence. My own investigations are at http://www.otago.ac.nz/density/pdfs/PRESSR2AppendixS3.pdf. It seems weights are best avoided.